# AWS Secret Manager best Practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, aws-secrets-manager

I have having a spring boot dockerize application running inside fargate cluster.This is application uses aurora DB.
I want to store DB password and API key in AWS Secret Manager.My idea was to make a API from Application and fetch the secret from secret maneger. But architect is saying this is not best approach.

What would be other better ways to achieve this ?

Comment: It is a good approach, you should be able to ask your architect why he/she thinks it is not the best appraoch.

Answer (score 3):

ECS provides a tutorial for specifying sensitive data to your cluster using Secrets Manager: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/specifying-sensitive-data-tutorial.html.

As for database credentials, if your application is written in Java, the best way to provide rotation-safe credentials to your application is to use the AWS-provided JDBC client library: https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-jdbc. Then you can safely setup rotation on your database credentials since the library will automatically pull from Secrets Manager and retry connections on authentication failures.

Comment: Secrets manager is the right place to store the API key, but for the database credentials there is no need to set up a password at all. Use IAM authentication instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [IAM Database authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html). Assign an IAM role to your Fargate task with permissions to access your Aurora cluster and voila! No password required.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into making your code call the Secrets Manager API directly? I wouldn't suggest building an API when one already exists, this can also be used to handle rotated credentials.

Starting point: [AWS Java SDK Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-java-example_code-secretsmanager.html)